# Get Metadata inside custom rpc call

Tags: rust, rpc, metadata

Hello I am creating custom rpc call, I need metadata to be able to decode extrinsics call inside my calls.

But I don't know how to get substrate metadata inside my rpc call?

Comment: Could you explain a little bit what your RPC call would do? or what is the expected input/output

Comment: Yes, sur in a custom rpc method, I am getting the extrinsics of a block, and I need to decode those extrinsics, but to do that I need to use Metadata. :-)

Comment: I see, it's interesting, but I would keep decoding processes outside of the custom RPC calls. It will affect the node performance under heavy loads of requests, as it will have to decode each time an RPC call is made. As Iker mentioned, you can perform this decoding process off chain, but that's just a suggestion. I look forward to see if anyone can help here!

Answer (score 3):

Conveniently, you have the relevant RPC method to get the metadata from a Substrate chain as the first example of [the custom RPC documentation on Substrate](https://docs.substrate.io/build/remote-procedure-calls/).

Additionally, if you are considering to use Polkadot.js, [this is the relevant method to get the metadata](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/runtime#metadata).

Finally, [this answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5554/how-to-add-custom-rpcs) should cover how to do this in a custom RPC call.

Comment: Thank you @Iker but I would like to do that in rust inside my custom RPC :-)

Comment: Perhaps this guide from my colleagues in support helps you building a custom RPC for your purposes: https://hackmd.io/JpJCbu0nTa2jym0za1Tggw

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: thank you I will take a look.

Comment: Hey @Iker, you might also like to consider looking at the subxt rust library, which provides similar functions to PolkadotJS but in rust: https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/

Comment: and this is the function you would use I  think: https://docs.rs/subxt/0.25.0/subxt/rpc/struct.Rpc.html#method.metadata