# How to add custom RPCs?

Tags: substrate-node-template, rpc, custom-rpc

I have the template pallet in the  [Substrate node template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template).
This pallet template has a function `do_something` that store a value in the storage.

I would like to create an RPC call that queries that value in the storage and make it accessible from my node.

How do I do this?

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped a lot! May I ask what is the trick to expose the RPC to the pallet interactor in the frontend? So far I was able to add the RPC call and do something, but I would like to use it from the ffronted ratehr than curl/Postman. Thanks again :)

Comment: Do you mean to interact with it using the polkadotJS UI: polkadot.js.org/apps/#/explorer or just do a RPC call with a frontend in JS?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Remote Procedure Calls, or RPCs, are a way for an external program—for example, a browser or front-end application—to communicate with a Substrate node.
> Substrate comes with several default [RPCs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc/) and you can also add your [custom RPC](https://docs.substrate.io/build/custom-rpc/) calls.

First of all create the custom RPC call in the template pallet and after set up the node for the pallet-template custom RPC.

## Add custom RPC in our pallet

Inside the pallet template folder create a new folder called rpc: `pallets/template/src/rpc`

The RPC call interacts with the pallet-tempate runtime API to call the function that gets the value. For that you need to create a pallet-template-runtime-api. Create a new folder inside the rpc folder: `pallets/template/src/rpc/runtime-api`

This folder can live anywhere you like, but because it defines an API that is closely related to a particular pallet, it makes sense to include the API definition in the pallet’s directory.

Create the `Cargo.toml` file for the runtime-api package. In `pallets/template/src/rpc/runtime-api/Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "pallet-template-runtime-api"
authors = ["Alex Bean <https://github.com/AlexD10S>"]
version = "1.0.0"
edition = "2021"

[package.metadata.docs.rs]
targets = ["x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"]

[dependencies]
sp-api = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.28", default-features = false }

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "sp-api/std",
]
```

And define the runtime API interface: `pallets/template/src/rpc/runtime-api/src/lib.rs`

The code to define the API is quite simple, and looks almost like any old Rust trait. The one addition is that it must be placed in the decl_runtime_apis! macro. This macro allows the outer node to query the runtime API at specific blocks. Although this runtime API only provides a single function, you may write as many as you like.

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

// Here we declare the runtime API. It is implemented it the `impl` block in
// runtime file (the `runtime/src/lib.rs`)
sp_api::decl_runtime_apis! {
    pub trait TemplateApi {
        fn get_value() -> u32;
    }
}
```

Now define the RPC. Create a folder `Cargo.toml` in the rpc folder: `pallets/template/src/rpc/Cargo.toml`

Here import the runtime-api defined before:

```
pallet-template-runtime-api = { path = "./runtime-api", default-features = false }
```

And the [JSON-RPC library](https://github.com/paritytech/jsonrpsee) for Rust.

```
jsonrpsee = { version = "0.15.1", features = ["server", "macros"] }
```

Full file:

```
[package]
name = "pallet-template-rpc"
version = "1.0.0"
edition = "2021"
authors = ["Alex Bean <https://github.com/AlexD10S>"]
description = 'RPC methods for the template pallet'

[package.metadata.docs.rs]
targets = ["x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"]

[dependencies]
codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.0.0", default-features = false, features = [
    "derive",
] }

jsonrpsee = { version = "0.15.1", features = ["server", "macros"] }


# Substrate packages

sp-api = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.28" }
sp-blockchain = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.28" }
sp-runtime = { default-features = false, version = "6.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.28" }

# local packages
pallet-template-runtime-api = { path = "./runtime-api", default-features = false }

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
  "sp-api/std",
  "sp-runtime/std",
  "pallet-template-runtime-api/std"
]
```

Inside the rpc folder create a src folder with a lib.rs where define the Pallet Template RPC:

**First define the RPC interface.**
Notice that the struct that implements the RPC needs a reference to the client. This is necessary so you can actually call into the runtime.

And the struct is generic over the BlockHash type. This is because it will call a runtime API, and runtime APIs must always be called at a specific block.

```
#[rpc(client, server)]
pub trait TemplateApi<BlockHash> {
    #[method(name = "template_getValue")]
    fn get_value(&self, at: Option<BlockHash>) -> RpcResult<u32>;
}

/// A struct that implements the `TemplateApi`.
pub struct TemplatePallet<C, Block> {
    // If you have more generics, no need to TemplatePallet<C, M, N, P, ...>
    // just use a tuple like TemplatePallet<C, (M, N, P, ...)>
    client: Arc<C>,
    _marker: std::marker::PhantomData<Block>,
}

impl<C, Block> TemplatePallet<C, Block> {
    /// Create new `TemplatePallet` instance with the given reference to the client.
    pub fn new(client: Arc<C>) -> Self {
        Self { client, _marker: Default::default() }
    }
}
```

**Now the RPC’s implementation.**
The additional syntax here is related to calling the runtime at a specific block, as well as ensuring that the runtime you’re calling actually has the correct runtime API available.

```
impl<C, Block> TemplateApiServer<<Block as BlockT>::Hash> for TemplatePallet<C, Block>
where
    Block: BlockT,
    C: Send + Sync + 'static + ProvideRuntimeApi<Block> + HeaderBackend<Block>,
    C::Api: TemplateRuntimeApi<Block>,
{
    fn get_value(&self, at: Option<<Block as BlockT>::Hash>) -> RpcResult<u32> {
        let api = self.client.runtime_api();
        let at = BlockId::hash(at.unwrap_or_else(||self.client.info().best_hash));

        api.get_value(&at).map_err(runtime_error_into_rpc_err)
    }
}

const RUNTIME_ERROR: i32 = 1;

/// Converts a runtime trap into an RPC error.
fn runtime_error_into_rpc_err(err: impl std::fmt::Debug) -> JsonRpseeError {
    CallError::Custom(ErrorObject::owned(
        RUNTIME_ERROR,
        "Runtime error",
        Some(format!("{:?}", err)),
    ))
    .into()
}
```

**The full file** in `pallets/template/src/rpc/src/lib.rs`:

```
pub use pallet_template_runtime_api::TemplateApi as TemplateRuntimeApi;
use jsonrpsee::{
    core::{Error as JsonRpseeError, RpcResult},
    proc_macros::rpc,
    types::error::{CallError, ErrorObject},
};
use sp_api::ProvideRuntimeApi;
use sp_blockchain::HeaderBackend;
use sp_runtime::{generic::BlockId, traits::Block as BlockT};
use std::sync::Arc;

#[rpc(client, server)]
pub trait TemplateApi<BlockHash> {
    #[method(name = "template_getValue")]
    fn get_value(&self, at: Option<BlockHash>) -> RpcResult<u32>;
}

/// A struct that implements the `TemplateApi`.
pub struct TemplatePallet<C, Block> {
    // If you have more generics, no need to TemplatePallet<C, M, N, P, ...>
    // just use a tuple like TemplatePallet<C, (M, N, P, ...)>
    client: Arc<C>,
    _marker: std::marker::PhantomData<Block>,
}

impl<C, Block> TemplatePallet<C, Block> {
    /// Create new `TemplatePallet` instance with the given reference to the client.
    pub fn new(client: Arc<C>) -> Self {
        Self { client, _marker: Default::default() }
    }
}

impl<C, Block> TemplateApiServer<<Block as BlockT>::Hash> for TemplatePallet<C, Block>
where
    Block: BlockT,
    C: Send + Sync + 'static + ProvideRuntimeApi<Block> + HeaderBackend<Block>,
    C::Api: TemplateRuntimeApi<Block>,
{
    fn get_value(&self, at: Option<<Block as BlockT>::Hash>) -> RpcResult<u32> {
        let api = self.client.runtime_api();
        let at = BlockId::hash(at.unwrap_or_else(||self.client.info().best_hash));

        api.get_value(&at).map_err(runtime_error_into_rpc_err)
    }
}

const RUNTIME_ERROR: i32 = 1;

/// Converts a runtime trap into an RPC error.
fn runtime_error_into_rpc_err(err: impl std::fmt::Debug) -> JsonRpseeError {
    CallError::Custom(ErrorObject::owned(
        RUNTIME_ERROR,
        "Runtime error",
        Some(format!("{:?}", err)),
    ))
    .into()
}
```

**Now modify the pallet implementation** to have a function called `get_value()`, in `pallets/template/src/lib.rs`
Change:

```
#[pallet::getter(fn something)]
```

with

```
#[pallet::getter(fn get_value)]
```

## Set up the node for the pallet-template Custom RPC

Implement now in the runtime of the node the function `get_value()` declared in the pallet-template-runtime-api

Add the runtime-api pallet in the configuration file of the pallet, in:

```
runtime/Cargo.toml
```

```
# local packages
pallet-template-runtime-api = { path = "./runtime-api", default-features = false }}
And add in the std:

std = [
    ...,
    "pallet-template-runtime-api/std",
]
```

Add the implementation of the runtime function in the pallet:

```
runtime/src/lib.rs
```

```
impl pallet_template_runtime_api::TemplateApi<Block> for Runtime {
    fn get_value() -> u32 {
        TemplateModule::get_value().unwrap_or(0)
    }
}
```

**Install the RPC in the node**
To add the node-specific RPC methods modify the files in the node to include the pallet RPC code manually.
First adding the new pallet in the configuration file in the `node/Config.toml`:

```
pallet-template-rpc = { version = "1.0.0", path = "../pallets/template/rpc" }
```

Then adding the node-specific RPC methods. Modify the file `node/rpc.rs` and there include the pallet template RPC code.

```
 /// Instantiate all full RPC extensions.
pub fn create_full<C, P>(
    deps: FullDeps<C, P>,
) -> Result<RpcModule<()>, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>
where
    C: ProvideRuntimeApi<Block>,
    C: HeaderBackend<Block> + HeaderMetadata<Block, Error = BlockChainError> + 'static,
    C: Send + Sync + 'static,
    C::Api: substrate_frame_rpc_system::AccountNonceApi<Block, AccountId, Index>,
    C::Api: pallet_transaction_payment_rpc::TransactionPaymentRuntimeApi<Block, Balance>,
    C::Api: pallet_template_rpc::TemplateRuntimeApi<Block>,
    C::Api: BlockBuilder<Block>,
    P: TransactionPool + 'static,
{
    use pallet_transaction_payment_rpc::{TransactionPayment, TransactionPaymentApiServer};
    use substrate_frame_rpc_system::{System, SystemApiServer};
    use pallet_template_rpc::{TemplatePallet, TemplateApiServer};

    let mut module = RpcModule::new(());
    let FullDeps { client, pool, deny_unsafe } = deps;

    module.merge(System::new(client.clone(), pool.clone(), deny_unsafe).into_rpc())?;
    module.merge(TransactionPayment::new(client.clone()).into_rpc())?;
    module.merge(TemplatePallet::new(client).into_rpc())?;

    // Extend this RPC with a custom API by using the following syntax.
    // `YourRpcStruct` should have a reference to a client, which is needed
    // to call into the runtime.
    // `module.merge(YourRpcTrait::into_rpc(YourRpcStruct::new(ReferenceToClient, ...)))?;`

    Ok(module)
}
```

Run the node and query the RPC using for an example CURL, in the command line:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "template_getValue", "params": []}' http://localhost:9933/
```

Comment: Hi @Alex thanks for sharing this. Do we have any video to demonstrate this?

Comment: Hi! There is not video tutorial about it (thanks for the feedback, I'd consider it)

Comment: You can take a look into the full code about it: https://github.com/AlexD10S/susbtrate-node-template/tree/rpc-custom-methods

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: To show it properly on the polkadot js apps UI (RPC calls) you need to add the custom RPC types to the API specs right here https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/tree/master/packages/apps-config/src/api/spec

Comment: Interesting, thanks!

Comment: following along we get an error:  runtime-api/src/lib.rs:5:1
   
   | |_^ use of undeclared crate or module `std`

Comment: The tutorial it's probably outdated, that's why is giving this error. Let me review it