# How to implement `into_rpc` method in jsonrpsee's rpc macro

Tags: substrate-node-template, rpc, jsonrpsee

I'm trying to add `custom RPC` to Substrate node template.
As explained in the jsonrpsee's proc_macro doc [here](https://github.com/paritytech/jsonrpsee/blob/master/examples/examples/proc_macro.rs), I define `BalancesApi` trait where #[rpc(server)] attribute added, and implement `BalancesApiServer` to the struct `Balances`.

I expect that macro implements `into_rpc` behind the scenes. However, compiler says no method named `into_rpc` found for struct `Balances` in the current scope.
[image]

If I expand macro, I can see `into_rpc` trait is generated,
[image]

How can I implement in on `BalancesApi` struct which will be used in `create_full` function? Some additional procedure is required?

Just an additional info, This is my working branch https://github.com/AstarNetwork/swanky-node/pull/67

Comment: This might not be a good questions, not being able to what could be an issue so far.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation looks good, but it seems like you are missing some import of the pallet-balances-rpc because there is a warning saying `BalancesApiServer` is unused.

You can try to follow this guide on StackExchange: [How to add custom RPCs?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5554/how-to-add-custom-rpcs), which is a step by step guide about how to create a custom RPC in the pallet template.

Comment: Thank you for your comment,
I thought `BalancesApiServer` is unused because `Balances` struct is not implementing `into_rpc` method.

I think I followed the how to guide (Thank you for the detailed contents!), but didn't find out what is the issue my implementation has.

The wired thing I found after posting this is if I remove a generic `P` which is for TransactionPool from the entire code base, then it compiles. `pallet-balances-rpc` package itself compiles, so that makes it difficult for me to know why `into_rpc` not implemented.

Comment: Now it compiles, but why `into_rpc` was not implemented is unknown.
It make sense if I get some trait bound error, but error about "not implemented" is not something I understand.

Answer (score 0):

The trait bounds are most likely not satisfied for the `into_rpc` impl, that's why your code won't compile.

You probably need additional trait bounds in your function for the params/return types satisfy `Send + Sync + serde::de::DeserializeOwned`.

Depending on context you may need `serde::se::Serialize` as well...